# Audio Books not playable on iPhone

Tags: itunes, audiobook

I have several audio books on my PC that are in .mp3 format.  I imported them through iTunes and changed the type to audio books.  I then right clicked on the audio book files and chose add to device->iPhone.  When I do a sync I can see it transferring the file but when I try to play the using Apple Books some of them just blink once when I click play and don't play and some play fine.

Comment: I ran across something similar with Audible. It seems that the quality and codec that is used to encode the audiobook can make a difference. Audible's solution is to prefer "high quality" audio books. Maybe if you check the quality of the MP3 (get info on the file, go to File and look at the bitrate and sample rate). Is it different between ones that work and ones that don't work?

Comment: Great idea checking the quality of the file.  I checked a working and non-working one and they were both 64kbps.  I have tried removing and re-syncing and nothing seems to work.

Comment: I have tried everything I know of but cannot get the books to play.  I guess I will have to load them on an MP3 player to listen to them.